# C# how to convert 4 byte to HEX 1 byte

Tags: hex, byte

the byte range I get from device via COM port is 30 30 32 3A
this is due to applying offset to every digit, so value comes as 4 bytes

after deleting 30H offset we get 00 00 02 0A, even thought the value is 2A (HEX)

finally I need to get value as one byte value 0x2A to read correct value 42 (DEC)
any help will be highly appreciated

**PS**: some explanations

**host to device command**:
command is 42 (2Ah) -> 002A, after applying 30H offset to each digit is presented as 30H 30H 32H 3AH

**device to host command**:
30H 30H 32H 3AH after deleting offset is presented as 00 00 02 0A need to be presented as 002A (2Ah)

Comment: What does your presentation code look like now?

Comment: Now it looks like array 00 00 02 0A and need to be 2A as one byte

Comment: The "H" does not look like you're just printing an array but like it's actual code that prints it in a specific hex format...?

Comment: H is just to show that value is in HEX format

Answer (score 0):

solved in the ways as follows

```
public static byte ByteArrayToByte(byte[] ba)
    {
        var str = BitConverter.ToString(ba).Replace("0", "").Replace("-", "");
        return Convert.ToByte(str, 16);
    }
```